# Contact page MVC workflow

Tags: php, model-view-controller

All my previous projects have had this workflow on Contact pages

1. User submits form
2. Controller gets `$_POST` details
3. Controller validates details (and sets error messages if necessary)
4. Controller sends email
5. Controller redirects to *thanks* page

Is this the standard workflow?

I used to validate everything in controllers, and then did some more reading and they recommended against it. Therefore, should I send the `$_POST` details to a helper type object and let it do all the work (validation/sending)?

Answer (score 0):

In controller we should only check validation. The main validation should be on model before operations with DB.

Answer (score 0):

The controller file need to check & validate the user input data.

After getting & accumulating all the data, it needs to transfer the data to the Model file for checking with the database (if needed) & then need to do some other works from here (like setting sessions / cookies, or sending mails, or firing hooks, ...). However, the control must come back to the same controller method, as all the previous model functionalities must be fired by a method call, from the same controller method.

The proper view method must be called now, and then the output must be rendered to the console.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is typically performed in the **`Model`**, not in the `Controller`.

This is because data structures are usually defined in the `Model` and  it is best to compare the acquired data immediately before manipulation (i.e. inserting into a database, etc.).